# Property binding matHeaderRowDef not used by any directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Here is the table html:

```html
<mat-table matSort class="inbox__messages" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

<!-- Building Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="building">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  <div class="inbox__messages__header">
    <h3 class="inbox__messages__header-label">Bâtiments</h3>
    <mat-form-field class="inbox__messages__dropdown">
      <mat-select placeholder="Choisir un bâtiment">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let building of buildings" [value]="building.value">
          {{ building.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <span class="inbox__messages__body-building">{{element.building}}</span>
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

 <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
(click)="expandedElement = row"></mat-row>
```

This error happens on ng test. What am I missing? I have imported MatHeaderRowDef into my component aswell as into the module.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We have had exactly the same issue concerning the property **matHeaderRowDef** and also **matRowDefColumns**.
We solved it by simply importing the material table module, *i.e.* **MatTableModule**, in the unit test *spec* file.

Specifically, we imported it in the initial declarations and then within the *beforeEach* block.

To better clarify, here is the *my-awesome.component.spec.ts* file:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyAwesomeComponent } from './my-awesome.component';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';

describe('MyAwesomeComponent', () => {
  let component: MyAwesomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyAwesomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyAwesomeComponent ],
      imports: [ MatTableModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyAwesomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is a much better solution than what I was doing: I was importing my Materials Module which forced me to also include the Animations Module

Comment: I have same issue in all of my components. I tried this solution, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Importing MatTableModule makes the error stop but if you're not testing any of the MatTableModule functionality, you can address this error with the right mock.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matHeaderRowDef]',
  inputs: ['columns: matHeaderRowDef']
})
export class MatHeaderRowDef { }
```

And then just throw MatHeaderRowDef in your TestBed declarations. The important part is the `inputs` property.

Answer (score 0):

To be complete, the mock is like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[matHeaderRowDef]',
  inputs: [
    'columns: matHeaderRowDef',
    'sticky: matHeaderRowDefSticky',
  ],
})
export class MockMatHeaderRowDefDirective { }
```

Identical mock for MatRowDef (just in case anyone needs that):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[matRowDef]',
  inputs: [
    'columns: matRowDefColumns',
    'when: matRowDefWhen',
  ],
})
export class MockMatRowDefDirective { }
```

And of course use the mock in the declarations of the TestBed:

```js
  beforeEach(async (): Promise<void> => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TableComponent,
        MockMatRowDefDirective,
        MockMatHeaderRowDefDirective,
        ...
      ],
      providers: [ ],
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Importing `MatTableModule` into specs file helps in resolving this issue